# css image rollover not working

Tags: css, image

I have a css image rollover that is supposed to display a couple of buttons.  It uses one image for 'normal' mode, one for 'hover' mode and one for 'active' mode.  The three images are part of one large image file.  I have implemented this method before on a different project and it worked fine, but for this project I cant seem to get the rollover effect working.  My code is below:

```
<div class="homealertbox"><h1 class="homealert">The Worlds Best Marketplace For Buying & Selling Websites</h1>
<div class="addbuttons">
    <a href="http://localhost/buy" class="buy"><span class="displace">Buy</span></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/sell" class="sell"><span class="displace">Sell</span></a>
</div>
```

My CSS is below:

```
a.buy {
display: block;
width: 160px;
height: 40px;
float:left;
background:url('http://localhost/img/buy.png');
background-position: 0 0;
}

a.buy:hover {
background:url('http://localhost/img/buy.png');
background-position:0 -40px;
}

a.buy:active {
background:url('http://localhost/img/buy.png');
background-position:0 -80px;
}

.displace {
position: absolute;
left: -5000px;
}

 a.sell {
display: block;
width: 160px;
height: 40px;
background: url('http://localhost/img/sell.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
float:right;
}

 a.sell:hover {
background: url('http://localhost/img/sell.png') 0 -40px no-repeat;
}

 a.sell:active {
background: url('http://localhost/img/sell.png') 0 -80px no-repeat;
}
```

I think the problem is to do with the nested div tags but I am not fully sure.  Can somebody help please?  Also, I apologize in advance if the code isnt formatted properly in this post.

Comment: Do any of the images show up?

Comment: You didn't close your homealertbox div, unless that closes further down after the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked for me. The only this I changed to test in my local machine was the URL of CSS image backgrounds. I created 2 images with 2 button backgrounds each and saved each as sell.png and buy.png.. I changed the localhost/... background path in CSS to where I had saved them. 
Check if your image path / url is correct and your images has the correct button backgrounds in correct locations. These are my images. [My Buy image](http://www.blissfulinterfaces.com/testing/buy.png)

[Working Demo](http://www.blissfulinterfaces.com/testing/test.html)